# Lock screen with different password (Mac)

Tags: macos, mac, security

[OSX 10.6]

Is there a way (or app) to enable screen locking with a different password from that of the current user.

I have a high-ish security password for my user account. The problem is that it is annoying to type every time I want access to my computer. I am not quite up for completely unlocking the screen given my peers. For unlocking my screen I would like something easy to type, even a single character would work.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this without compromising my user password?

Comment: You could try asking the author of [Keyboard Cleaner](http://jan.prima.de/~jan/plok/archives/48-Keyboard-Cleaner.html) for a variant of it that instead of `Cmd-Q` quits when a custom keystroke (not shown on screen) is hit. Or program it yourself. Just swallowing all input might not even be that difficult to do.

Answer (score 1):

No.

There's no way to do this. The lock screen is tied to the user's account.

Comment: Consider deleting this answer, so the question shows up as unanswered. There might be acceptable alternatives (see my comment); from what it sounds like the user doesn't exactly need lock screen security.